# Erro de permissão ao renomear arquivo via PHP

Tags: php

```
$dir = "arquivo/"; 

$file = $_FILES["csv1"];

//Move o arquivo da pasta temporaria de upload para a pasta de destino

if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], "$dir/".$file["name"])) { 
    rename($file["name"], "novonome.csv");  
    echo "Arquivo enviado com sucesso!"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "Erro, o arquivo não pode ser enviado."; 
}
```

Erro:

> Warning: rename(dados.csv,novonome.csv): Permission denied in /var/www/html/importador_de_csv/arquivo.php on line 11

Já tentei dar permissão a pasta e ao arquivo, só preciso renome-a-lo após muda-lo de pasta

Comment: Dê uma lida nesse manual vai te ajudar. https://php.net/rename

Comment: Use o caminho para o arquivo, não só o nome: `rename($file["tmp_name"], "$dir/novonome.csv")`

Comment: você ja pode passar o novo nome dele dentro da função 'move_uploaded_file'
exemplo: move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], "$dir/".$novonome)